# TypeLoadException was unhandled in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I'm fairly new to C#, and am having a problem when loading a library into my program. Im trying to run [this](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html) example in visual studio, but I am getting an error:

```
TypeLoadException was unhandled. Can't load type SVM.Problem from assembly SVM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SVM;

namespace SVM
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //First, read in the training data.
        Problem train = Problem.Read("a1a.train");
        Problem test = Problem.Read("a1a.test");

        //For this example (and indeed, many scenarios), the default
        //parameters will suffice.
        Parameter parameters = new Parameter();
        double C;
        double Gamma;

        //This will do a grid optimization to find the best parameters
        //and store them in C and Gamma, outputting the entire
        //search to params.txt.
        ParameterSelection.Grid(train, parameters, "params.txt", out C, out Gamma);
        parameters.C = C;
        parameters.Gamma = Gamma;

        //Train the model using the optimal parameters.
        Model model = Training.Train(train, parameters);

        //Perform classification on the test data, putting the
        //results in results.txt.
        Prediction.Predict(test, "results.txt", model, false);
    }
}
```

}

I have added the dll as a reference via the solution explorer. What could be going wrong?

---

I have started a new project, added the dll as a reference, ran the project and now everything works. Very frustrating not to know what went wrong, but I suspect it had something to do with the project name and the dll name being the same. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Need from details, which assemblies are Program and Problem in. Which line causes the exception. What platform are each of you assemblies compiled in, are the references version specific? Did you try to delete the bin and obj directories and rebuild?

Comment: What do you mean with assembly? There is no line mentioned that causes the error unfortunately

Comment: EXE and DLLs are called assemblies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, due to your answer, I've now managed to reproduce the problem without SVM. Basically, you shouldn't have two assemblies with the same name, one in a .exe and one in a .dll. Here's an example:

Library.cs:

```
public class Library
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Library.Foo");
    }
}
```

Test.cs:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Library.Foo();
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
> csc /target:library /out:Test.dll Library.cs
> csc /r:Test.dll Test.cs
```

Run:

```
> test.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Library' from
assembly 'Test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.+
    at Test.Main(String[] args)
```

It's already loaded an assembly called `Test` from Test.exe... so it's not going to *also* look for Test.dll.

Comment: thanks, where can I changed this variable? Would it help if I manually copied the dll to the project folder?

Comment: @Freek8: If you look at the "Properties" window when you've got the reference highlighted, it should be shown there. How did you try to run the program? How did you add the reference?

Comment: I right-clicked on references > Add and selected the dll. CopyLocal was already true. I ran the program via Debug > Start Debugging

Comment: @Freek8: If you browse to the bin/Debug or bin/Release directory, do you see both your executable and the DLL there? If you double-click on it, does that work? I've tried your code, and didn't get that problem...

Comment: thanks for your reply again, I can see both the .dll and the executable. If I run the executable I receive the very same error.

Comment: @Freek8: Sounds very odd, I'm afraid... no idea.

Comment: btw I think the library is not-so-recent (as in from 2009), could this be an issue?

Comment: @Freek8: Shouldn't be a problem. Out of interest, if you rename the DLL to something else, do you get the same error or a different one?

Comment: when renaming it the same problem still occurs. I have a clean installation of VS2010 so that shouldnt be a problem either

Comment: @Freek8: I've had an idea... right-click on the DLL, and open up the "Properties" box - is there a button saying "Unblock"? If so, click that and then try again.

Comment: nope, there's no button unblock. The library is working now for me (see my answer to the question). However, I still don't know what caused it Thanks again for helping Jon

Comment: @Freek8: See my edit. You were right about it being due to names. Hopefully my answer sheds a bit more light now :)

Comment: +1 - This answer was immensely helpful.  FWIW, Mono on my Mac has no trouble loading an exe and a dll with the same name.

Comment: In my solution I did this mistake.. in the project properties I set the same name for the 2 projects and I got the error! Thank to your solution I found the issue. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add this as a comment (but not high enough rep yet) - I had this exact issue and found @JonSkeet answer really useful, between myself and a colleague we stumbled on the answer;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236893/692942.

Basically my project assembly which generated an EXE file was named the same as a referenced assembly I built as a class library. The combination of the EXE and DLL in the build directory cause the error to be thrown as only one assembly of that name could be loaded.