# System.TypeLoadException in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I have a C# application and I modified it to show a new window using the lines:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   WelcomeScreen channelBar = new WelcomeScreen(true, "http://www.trade-ideas.com/cms_static/ChannelBar/channelbar.html");
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when I run the app and click on the button, I get this error:

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load type     'TradeIdeas.TIProData.OddsMakerColumnConfiguration' from assembly 'TIProData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

What doesn't make any sense is that WelcomeScreen comes from TIProGUI.dll not TIProData. I have included both dll's in the project along with a 3rd dll:

```
using TradeIdeas.TIProData;
using TradeIdeas.TIProGUI;
using TradeIdeas.TIProData.Configuration;
```

Also, when I run the project initially, I see a very strange message.  It says:

```
Loading symbols from TIProData.dll from:
\\MissionControl\Users\KLewis2\Documents\CVSRoot\C_Sharp\TIProData\Obj\Release
```

Needless to say, there is no path to that from my machine.

Any clues as to what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here, this should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623694/typeloadexception-was-unhandled-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons and one of common once is exceptions in static initializers.

To diagnose - debug program with exceptions set to "break when thrown" and disabled "my code only". When exception happen take note of call stack and check all exceptions thrown from static initializers.

Location of options:

- Tools-> Options -> Debug -> My Code only (uncheck)
- Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions (check "thrown")

Sample code that will cause that error:

```
class MyClass
{
      static int value = ReadFromConifg();

      static int  ReadFromConifg()
      {...
           throw new ConfigMissingException();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.  Can you see my last edit about loading symbols from some strange network path?  Can I see anywhere in my project where it is attempting to load symbols from?

Comment: @user3229570 Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols, or for each on Wiindow->Modules-> right click on module.